Book recommendations for the Sieve of Eratosthenes?
I was reading the Sieve of Eratosthenes section in An Introduction to Sieve Methods and Their Applications by Cojocaru and Murty; Sieve methods by Richert and Halberstam; Opera de Cribro by Iwaniec and Friedlander and I was wondering if people knew any other good books that talked about the Sieve of Eratosthenes in detail.
I tried searching the Sieve of Eratosthenes directly for the book title, but was unable to find any.
I also tried just searching the word sieve and got 31 results, but I am not sure which one would be the most suitable for learning the Sieve of Eratosthenes (plus some books may not even have the English word "sieve" in the title but still have a good section on the Sieve of Eratosthenes, such as Iwaniec and Friedlander's Opera de Cribro). Hence the question...
Thank you very much for your recommendations in advance!

I removed the image links, they make your post very long and difficult to read. If you want, you can convert them to web links, on which people can click to see, but don't include them inline.

Some pointers to the literature: 1 and 2 and 3
